# Oracle SQL: Count Weekdays of a Calendar Week

Tags: sql, oracle, select, calendar, weekday

So I want to make a query to show me if a certain calendar week has all 7 Day.
It would be okay if it just returns the numbers 1-7.

The table that I have contains articles of the 3 month of 2020 but even so the first week just contains Wednesday to Sunday it still counts it as a calendar week.

With that select I would make pl/sql Script to check it and if yes something happens.

This is an example of the Table:

```
Date        Articel_Id
14.10.2020  78
15.10.2020  80
16.10.2020  96
17.10.2020  100
18.10.2020  99
```

Can I Use to_char() to check if Calendar Week has all 7 Days ?
If yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenging is actually defining the weeks.  If you want to define them using the ISO standard, then aggregate:

```
select to_char(date, 'IYYYY-IW') as yyyyww,
       count(distinct trunc(date)) as num_days
from t
group by to_char(date, 'IYYYY-IW')
order by yyyyww;
```

This counts the number of days per week.  I'm not sure if you want to filter, have a flag, or what the result set should look like.  For filtering, using a `having` clause, such as `having count(distinct trunc(date)) = 7`.

Comment: can i add an " Where count(distinct trunc(angelegt_am)) = 7 "  to it ?

i tried it but therre is an error..

select to_char(date, 'IYYYY-IW') as yyyyww,
       count(distinct trunc(date)) as num_days
from date
where count(distinct trunc(date)) = 7
group by to_char(date, 'IYYYY-IW')
order by yyyyww;

Comment: Nevermind, i got it :D

thank you very much!

Comment: Proper format according to ISO-8601 would be `'IYYY-"W"IW'` - `IYYYY` is wrong, must be `IYYY`